# Cómo colocar los <option> de un <select> en un array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un select con una lista de opciones de los cuales no sé su valor.

Debo, mediante jQuery, escoger cuál de esos será cargado por defecto.

Pensé solucionarlo metiendo los en un array[] y luego inyectarlo mediante:

```
 $("#option").val();
 $("#option").change();
```

Pero no sé cómo meter esos option en un array.

Por ejemplo, si deseo que el option mostrador por defecto sea el de la posición número 3, debería imprimir el que se encuentra en array[2]

tengo el siguiente código en el html:

```
<section id="MiSeccion">
 <option value="x">Opción 1</option>
 <option value="x">Opción 2</option>
</section>
```

La idea es mediante Jquery determinar cuál será el option que se mostrará por defecto, tenía pensado meterlos en un array y luego mediante $("#MiSeccion").val() asignarle el opción que deberá mostrar por defecto ya que de antemano no sabré que valores tomarán las x de los values; si conocen una mejor manera les agradezco me la expliquen.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el `html` exacto que tienes, la una condición que se necesitas aplicar y el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];

$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#miSelect > option").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).html())
  });
  console.log(arr)
});
```

```html
<select id="miSelect">
  <option>Opcion 1</option>
  <option>Opcion 2</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Definiremos una variable para almacenar los datos

El `$(document).ready` detecta cuando el documento está listo para mostrarse

El selector `#miSelect > option` es para referirnos a cada uno de los `option` del elemento con el id `miSelect`

El método `.push()` inserta un elemento en un array

Al final, veremos en la consola el resultado

Comment: Disculpa, y luego como hago para que desde Jquery decirle, por ejemplo, que quiero que muestre por defecto el option que se encuentra en la posición array[1], desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: `console.log(arr[1]);`

Comment: Discúlpame, no me di a entender, necesito que me lo muestre en el <section> del html, es decir, si pongo que me muestre el array[1], en la lista desplegable del section debe aparecerme opción 2 como valor por defecto (asumiendo que arr[0]="opción 1", arr[1]="opción 2"), intenté poniendo la propiedad .val(arr[1]) pero me da error.

Comment: `$("select > option:first-child").html(arr[1])` si te sigue dando error es porque arr no está definido

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado bastante!!!